# How do I display a single div with a controller in another table?

Tags: jquery, search, html

I'm making a simple single page navigation site for an instruction manual and can't seem to get my JQuery search working correctly. What I am trying to do is have the user select a link from a navigation panel on the left side of the screen and then have the appropriate div appear in the area to the right.

Here is my script that I am using to find the div associated with what the user clicks:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contentArea  div').hide(); //hide divs on load using parent class as a starting point           
    $('.ac-container ol').click(function() {  //function fires when clicking list item inside of ac-container.
        var divFinder = $('#contentArea > div.value()').eq($(this).index('.ac-container'));  // get the relevant div
        console.log(divFinder);
        divFinder.show();  // show the relevant div
        $('#contentArea div').not(divFinder).hide();  // hide all but the relevant div
    })
});
```

Here is a sample of the Markup:

```
        <section class="ac-container">
            <label for="ac-2">II. Browser Setup</label>
            <article class="ac-medium">
            <ol type='A'>
                <li><div id="dsection2_1">General Tab</div></li>
                <li><div id="dsection2_2">Security Tab</div></li>
                <li><div id="dsection2_3">Pop Up Blocker</div></li>
            </ol>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>
```

And the area with the divs that I'm hiding/showing:

```
<td style="background-color:#eeeeee;height:200px;width:1300px;vertical-align:top;" id="contentArea">
<div style="background-color:red; max-width:100%;" id="section1_1">
    <p>This is an item in DIV 1</p>
    <p>This is another item in DIV 1</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color:blue; max-width:100%;" id="section2_2">
    <p>This is an item in DIV 2</p>
    <p>This is another item in DIV 2</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color:Yellow; max-width:100%;" id="section3_3">
    <p>This is an item in DIV 3</p>
    <p>This is another item in DIV 3</p>
</div>
```

I apologize if some of my formatting is bad, this is my first time posting here and I'm a noob with the code tool...

Anyways, when I put static values into my index in Jquery, I get positive results, meaning if I type:

```
var divFinder = $('#section2_2').eq($(this).index('#dsection2_2'));
```

...it will hide the first and third divs, and show the second one (correct behavior). However, when I have it the way shown above, it will not match up with anything and just return the last div. I'm sure it is a simple fix, but I cannot seem to figure this one out today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

HTML (I added some classes and removed the `div` children of the `li` elements):

```
<section class="ac-container">
    <div>
        <label for="ac-2">II. Browser Setup</label>
        <article class="ac-medium">
            <ol type='A'>
                <li class="one">General Tab</li>
                <li class="two">Security Tab</li>
                <li class="three">Pop Up Blocker</li>
            </ol>
        </article>
    </div>
</section>
<div id="contentArea">
    <div class="one" style="background-color:red; max-width:100%;" id="section1_1">
        <p>This is an item in DIV 1</p>
        <p>This is another item in DIV 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two" style="background-color:blue; max-width:100%;" id="section2_2">
        <p>This is an item in DIV 2</p>
        <p>This is another item in DIV 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three" style="background-color:Yellow; max-width:100%;" id="section3_3">
        <p>This is an item in DIV 3</p>
        <p>This is another item in DIV 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contentArea  div').hide();           
    $('.ac-container li').click(function() {
        var clicked = $(this);
        var cls = $('li').map(function(){
            return $(this).attr('class');
        });
        for (i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
            if (clicked.hasClass(cls[i])) {
                $('#contentArea div.' + cls[i]).toggle();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pfgp/2/

Comment: That is it, that you so much. There was a bit of variation, I had to add $('#contentArea div').not('#contentArea div.' + cls[i]).hide(); but you definitely put me in the right direction, thank you again so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% clear on how this bit is intended to be working:

```
var divFinder = $('#contentArea > div.value()').eq($(this).index('.ac-container'));  // get the relevant div
```

but you're just feeding the jquery selector a hard-coded string '#contentArea > div.value()', which means that it's going to look for an element of type `<div.value()>` within an element of id contentArea. It's not evaluating that div.value() call since it's within the quotes, nor would div.value() do anything that I can make sense of even if it were being evaluated. I've been staring at your code and trying to figure out what exactly the line is doing with the indexes and I honestly can't quite make heads or tails of it... but in an broad sense your problem is that the info you're passing it is not correct.

Comment: I THINK the OP was trying to match the hidden divs with the list item clicked based on index. I just took that out entirely and gave the elements some classes and matched them that way.